# Check if user has already logged-in via google API oauth2

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, google-api, token

Users can log in my website using their google credentials throuth the google API using OAuth2. For doing so I've been following this tutorial : http://www.saaraan.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php

It's working great so far except it's all in a single php file. Now I want to create a separate PHP file that simply says 'YES' if the user has already logged-in on the login page, or 'NO' if it hasn't. I've tried different things such as :

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    print "yes";
}else
{
    print "no";
}
```

It's not working as $client doesn't exist as it has been defined in the other login page. How can I check on each pages of my website if a user has already logged in through google API ?

Answer (score 1):

I made the following function to check if the user has already logged-in. It works, but I'm not sure that's the right way of doing it :

```
function logged_in($client)
{
    if($client->getAccessToken())
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```